# how to work out lightning PyTorch and dgl DataLoader batch size set to None problem

Tags: pytorch-lightning, dgl

I am currently working on a model where I need to pass a specific batch size to my dgl.Dataloader but when used with Lightning PyTorch I get the following warning:

Trying to infer the `batch_size` from an ambiguous collection. The batch size we found is 2998. To avoid any miscalculations, use `self.log(..., batch_size=batch_size)`.

And once looking at the DGL documentations they mentioned something as below but I still cannot find out what to do to make the Dataloader not return None for batch_size.

> ## (BarclayII) PyTorch Lightning sometimes will recreate a DataLoader
>
> from an existing
> # DataLoader with modifications to the original arguments.  The arguments are retrieved
> # from the attributes with the same name, and because we change certain arguments
> # when calling super().**init**() (e.g. batch_size attribute is None even if the
> # batch_size argument is not, so the next DataLoader's batch_size argument will be
> # None), we cannot reinitialize the DataLoader with attributes from the previous
> # DataLoader directly.
>
> A workaround is to check whether "collate_fn" appears in kwargs.  If
> "collate_fn"
> # is indeed in kwargs and it's already a CollateWrapper object, we can assume that
> # the arguments come from a previously created DGL DataLoader, and directly initialize
> # the new DataLoader from kwargs without any changes.